# Is Rtools incompatible with R version 3.5.1?

Tags: r, rtools

I have tried `install.packages("Rtools")`, but this provides an error that states

> package ‘Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Given that the latest version of R is just a week old, should I wait for the R developers to catch up, or is this a bug I should report?

Comment: Rtools is not an R package. download the .exe file from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and start the installer by double clicking it.

Answer (score 10):

No, I think it's related to `devtools`. You can check that `devtools:::version_info` is lacking `3.5`. You could use this as a workaround:

```
library(devtools)
assignInNamespace("version_info", c(devtools:::version_info, list("3.5" = list(version_min = "3.3.0", version_max = "99.99.99", path = "bin"))), "devtools")
```

Now your install commands for any package that needs compilation will work again, assuming you have version 3.5 of it installed from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.

See here for reference: https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1772

Comment: The `devtools` version `2.0.1` does not have version_info at all. Do you how this can be fixed?

Comment: I noticed, but these problems were solved since version 2.0.0. Isn’t that the case for you then?

Comment: I cannot install a previous version of `rlang`. This is what is tried after your answer. `devtools::install_version('rlang', '0.1.6', repo = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')`