# Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp(): Error 1 occurred building shared library

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to use the `mixl` package in R for discrete choice modelling. `mixl` includes a pre-compiler that takes a model specification written in plain text, and converts it to a C++ utility function callable from R.

I run R in Windows 10. I have installed the `Rtools` successfully and added the R executable path (*C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin*) into the environment variables list.

```
> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE

> install.Rtools(check = T)
No need to install Rtools - You've got the relevant version of Rtools installed
```

I have installed the `Rcpp` package but when running the following code

```
library(mixl)
data("Train", package = "mlogit")
Train$ID <- Train$id
Train$CHOICE <- as.numeric(Train$choice)
mixl_test <- "
ASC_B_RND <- @ASC_B + draw_1*@SIGMA_B;
TIME_A_RND <- @B_timeA + draw_2*@SIG_time;
TIME_B_RND <- @B_timeB + draw_2*@SIG_time;
U_PT <- @B_price*$price_A/1000 + TIME_A_RND*$time_A/60 + @B_change*$change_A;
U_Car <- ASC_B_RND + (@B_price*$price_B/1000 + TIME_B_RND*$time_B/60);
"
model_spec <- specify_model(mixl_test, Train)
```

the following error message comes up.

```
> C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/Users/takaa/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/mixl/include"  -I"C:/Users/takaa/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/takaa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOks2bQ/sourceCpp-x86_64-w64-mingw32-1.0.2"     -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c file2fbc33473a13.cpp -o file2fbc33473a13.o
file2fbc33473a13.cpp: In function 'void utilityFunction(Rcpp::NumericVector, UF_args2&)':
file2fbc33473a13.cpp:127:1: error: 'ASC_B_RND' was not declared in this scope
 ASC_B_RND <- ASC_B + draw[0]*SIGMA_B;

> ^
> 
> file2fbc33473a13.cpp:128:1: error: 'TIME_A_RND' was not declared in this scope
 TIME_A_RND <- B_timeA + draw[1]*SIG_time;
> 
> ^
> 
> file2fbc33473a13.cpp:129:1: error: 'TIME_B_RND' was not declared in this scope
 TIME_B_RND <- B_timeB + draw[1]*SIG_time;
> 
> ^
> 
> make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf:215:
> file2fbc33473a13.o] Error 1 
> 
> Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp(code =
> e1$cpp_code, env = cpp_container) :    Error 1 occurred building
> shared library.
>
```

I believe the questions is similar to [[Error 1 occurred building shared library while sourcing cpp code inside R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266286/error-1-occurred-building-shared-library-while-sourcing-cpp-code-inside-r?noredirect=1&lq=1][1]) and [https://github.com/aidenlab/straw/issues/20][2] but I have rebooted Rstudio and Windows (and nothing changed) and concerning the second question should I change to `-std=c++11` from `-std=gnu++11`? Has Anyone faced a similar problem, what is the issue here?

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what this has to do with Rcpp -- but maybe you want to talk to the authors of `mixl` ?

Comment: are you sure you are supposed to use `<-` for assignments in the model specification? the error message looks as if it was taken over to C++ where it has avery different meaning.

Comment: Thank you @RalfStubner you are right, I can't believe I didn't check that one, it did work with `=`. Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel for the comment too, can I ask you how you could tell this was not an Rcpp related issue?

Comment: @transmod_kdtk  Because by the same logic of "but I am using Rcpp underneath" it also a bug in R, the `gcc` compiler, and eventually your Intel hardware.  Kidding aside, that was just between you and `mixl` which itself was using Rcpp "as advertised".